# error in google login api script in react js

Tags: reactjs, react-google-login

I'm trying to use the new Google OAuth 2.0 API In my Web Application I'm getting Error in my application like
Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined

**Index.html** code

```html
<body>
      <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
      <script src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client" async defer></script>
      <div id="root"></div> 
</body>
```

**App.js** code below

```js
function handleCallbackResponse(response) {
  console.log("Encoded JWT ID Token :" + response.credential);
  var userObject = jwt_decode(response.credential);
  console.log(userObject);
  setUser(userObject);
  
  if (user !== null) {
    history.push("/profileSetup/P3");
  }}
  
  
  useEffect(() => {
  /*global google*/
  google.accounts.id.initialize({
    client_id:
      "*****************************************.apps.googleusercontent.com",
    callback: handleCallbackResponse,
  });
  google.accounts.id.renderButton(
    document.getElementById("SignInDiv"),
    {
      theme: "outline",
      shape: "circle",
      width: "270",
      text: "signin_with",
      logo_alignment: "center",
    }
  );
  google.accounts.id.prompt();}, []);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: window.google.*

Answer (score 0):

You can access 'google' object which is getting from the script file like this.

```
window.google
```

So the whole code look like this

```
useEffect( () => {
/*Global Google*/
window.google.accounts.id.initialize( {
  client_id: "569455791412-mfj5jfk52epmc9ttc3kbibunk5deqhgb.apps.googleusercontent.com",
  callback: handleCallBackResponse

});

window.google.accounts.id.renderButton(
  document.getElementById("singInDiv"),
  {
    theme:"outline", size:"large"
  }
);
```

}, []);